# Clojureql - Can't take value of a macro (clojure)

Tags: clojure, clojureql

I need to generate the following:

```
(clojureql.core/join (clojureql.core/table db :tableA) (clojureql.core/table db :tableA)
     (clojureql.core/where (apply and (= :tableA.id :tableB.id)
                      [(apply or [(clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [1 2])
                                  (clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [3 4])])])))
```

But the "apply or" form needs to be "passed" from another function or macro. Here's what I mean:

```
(clojureql.core/join (clojureql.core/table db :tableA) (clojureql.core/table db :tableA)
     (clojureql.core/where (apply and (= :tableA.id :tableB.id)
                      [(my-or-f)])))
```

where this function is:

```
(defn my-or-f []
    (apply or [(clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [1 2])
         (clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [3 4])]))
```

however this function throws this exception:

```
#<CompilerException java.lang.Exception: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/or (NO_SOURCE_FILE:2)>
```

I've also tried using a macro. It compiles but it throws the same exception when I try running the query using this macro

```
(defmacro my-or-f []
    `(apply or [(clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [1 2])
         (clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [3 4])]))
```

Is there another way that I could use the "apply or"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that macros are not functions - they run at compile time and are passed the actual syntax (lists and symbols, primarily), so you can't apply them at runtime to runtime datastructures.  Thus, `(apply or my-list)` throws an error.  You have a few options:

```
(def my-list (list false false 4 false 5))

(some identity my-list) -- returns 4
(reduce #(or %1 %2) my-list) -- returns 4
```

In practice, you probably want `some` -- it stops as soon as it reaches an element that returns true, while `reduce` always traverses the entire list.

Note: you will also have the same problem with your `(apply and ...)` -- `(every? identity ...)` will do what you want.

In this case, however, why do you need to use `apply` at all?  This should work equally well:

```
(clojureql.core/join (clojureql.core/table db :tableA) (clojureql.core/table db :tableA)
                     (clojureql.core/where (and (= :tableA.id :tableB.id)
                                                (my-or-f))))

(defn my-or-f []
  (or (clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [1 2])
      (clojureql.predicates/in :tableA.id [3 4])))
```

One last suggestion - when you `require` clojureql.predicates, if you replace `clojureql.predicates` with `[clojurecl.predicates :as qlp]`, you can use `qlp` in place of `clojureql.predicates` in the rest of the file, which makes the above (if we also replace `clojureql.core` with `qlc`):

```
(qlc/join (qlc/table db :tableA) (qlc/table db :tableA)
          (qlc/where (and (= :tableA.id :tableB.id)
                          (my-or-f))))

(defn my-or-f []
  (or (qlp/in :tableA.id [1 2])
      (qlp/in :tableA.id [3 4])))
```

which is much easier to read.

For the purposes of ClojureQL, try `(apply clojureql.predicates/or* ...)` and `(apply clojureql.predicates/and* ...)`.  clojureql's `where` replaces any `and` and `or` it sees with `clojureql.predicates/and*` and `clojureql.or*`, so doing this replacement yourself should work.  Both `and*` and `or*` are functions, not macros, so there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: Retief, I've tried your suggestion however this doesn't work with the clojureql library. here's the sql that it generates: SELECT tableA.*,tableA.* FROM tableA JOIN tableA ON ((tableA.id = tableB.id) AND tableA.id IN (1,2))   but the sql that I need to generate (from my first working example) is:   SELECT tableA.*,tableA.* FROM tableA JOIN tableA ON ((tableA.id = tableB.id) AND (tableA.id IN (1,2) OR tableA.id IN (3,4)))

Comment: The issue is that clojureQL/where is a macro that walks the source tree that you pass it, looking for math, `and` and `or`.  In a normal environment, my code would work fine, but this doesn't work for clojureQL.  There's probably a workaround, but unfortunately, I don't actually use clojureQL, so I don't know it.  One thing that might work is to take my final suggestion (with no list operations) and make my-or-f a macro.

Comment: @RonP check my edit - I found the information by checking through the clojureql source [here](https://github.com/LauJensen/clojureql)

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of parameters you are giving `or` is known, this is probably the easiest solution:

```
(apply #(or %1 %2) [nil 10]) ; => 10
```